# after update trigger mysql dont execute if a field is change whatever null or not null or empty

Tags: mysql

i have table **person** and the column is **name** and **email**.

then i have **trigger after update** that insert value to **table logger**

but in my case

i dont want to execute **insert** ***IF***

1. name is null OR
2. name is not null OR
3. name is empty OR

so i just want execute logger when only field email has on change/update.

these my trigger

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS person__aus;
CREATE TRIGGER person__aus 
AFTER UPDATE 
ON person FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF OLD.name THEN // how to implement the three condition on above to dont execute, thats mean only execute these line when only column email has any change
        INSERT INTO person_logger SELECT 'update', NULL, NOW(), d.* FROM person AS d WHERE d.id = NEW.id; // here is i copy the value with three dynamic value 'flag', 'auto-increment', dateTime, and person new value.
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: *i dont want to execute insert IF 1.name is null OR 2.name is not null OR 3.name is empty* WHAT name? old? new? any of? PS. do you understand that `name is null OR name is not null` means "always"?

Comment: In case or analogic if we dont touch the name column tried to trigger the trigger. If we touch the column name or change dont try to trigger the trigger. We can simply that case into touch . So what ever on change is NULL or empty or Have value dont try to update, there is any flag or tricky on db driver mysql ?

Comment: We can assume here . First name is null after insert. Then i update the name into 'hello world' ( in here i dont want to trigger my after update ) . Then if update name into null or empty ( i still dont want to trigger my after update ) . I just only want to trigger the after update only on email changes.

Comment: A trigger will fire on an update to any column and that cannot be influenced by you. However 'In an UPDATE trigger, you can use OLD.col_name to refer to the columns of a row before it is updated and NEW.col_name to refer to the columns of the row after it is updated' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html - so up to you to code appropriately.

Comment: @P.Salmon hmm okey i could there is have any chance or tricky on driver db but the scope only on mysql :( , its same what i think about trigger AU . Ah i got it let me try with NEW and OLD logic . I still hope there is have option like as 'select or from or where' to directly indicate dont execute for that column